# nested scriptblocks in a powershell remote session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to run a script block on a remote machine, but i don't to be prompted for credentials, i want to pass them in the script.
 Some commands may but the commands i want to run are access denied unless i provide the credential.

for example this command can work:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable $Error -Scriptblock {ls }
```

but this wont work unless -credential is passed (Invoke-Command on target)

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable $Error -Scriptblock {Invoke-Command -computername $Env:COMPUTERNAME -Credential $Cred  -ScriptBlock {ls} }
```

the same way what i want to achieve causes access denied problem (starting a process)

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable $Error -Scriptblock {[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("C:\Myprocess.exe", $localArgs, "UserName", $credential.Password, "MyDomain")}
```

Comment: Interesting reading: http://tfl09.blogspot.it/2013/02/powershell-remoting-double-hop-problem.html

Answer (score 0):

```
   Invoke-Command -Session $session -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable $setError -Scriptblock {$Domain = "domain";$PassSec = ConvertTo-SecureString $( "password") -AsPlainText -Force ; $Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $($domain + "\" + "userName"),$passSec; Invoke-Command -computername $Env:COMPUTERNAME -Credential $Cred  -ScriptBlock {C:\Myprocess.exe } }
```